# Full Verification & Validation of Image-Based Backups

Tags: backup, validation, verification

## Intro and some terminology

Hello to the community of “Super User”!

As the title implies, my question is about the process of full (complete) verification & validation of image-based backups. But first, a small remark: I suppose, there is a little bit of confusion in the usage of terms "Verification" and "Validation", because the same process (for example, testing created image in VM) referred on different resources both as a “Verification” and as a “Validation”. That’s why clarification here (in comments or in answers) would be good. But without going into such terminology details: I am asking here about **how to check that just the right data was copied just exactly** (i. e. in full, down to every single bit). And by “Verification & Validation” (for simplicity just “V&V” further in the text) I mean here exactly such a check

## Some assumptions

And because backup is a rather large branch (field), I think, some more assumptions should be introduced:

1. Let’s consider here questions of backups of operating systems (with all system partitions required to normal boot and with the user files, of course) as this type of backup, I think, is one of the most general backup tasks (and other backup cases may be considered as just a special and more simple case of OS backup)
2. Also, for generality let’s review all most common storage types (as source drives for backup, i. e. on which OS is installed): so, it’s SSDs and HDDs (both CMR and SMR)
3. Let’s consider hardware without any malfunctions and errors
4. And let’s omit questions of storing backups and assume that data, which backup software has written, is stored exactly (without any unwanted modifications), so focus here only on V&V stage
5. As for OS’s and filesystems, I suppose, process won’t differ much for one or the other OS or FS. My question is formulated with emphasis mainly on Windows and NTFS (simply because I know and use these systems more than others), but answers with a focus on any OS would be great

## Review of most often suggested strategies for backup V&V

For backup V&V these strategies (in different resources: software documentation, articles, blogs, etc.), which, in my opinion, are not complete (and I explain why I think so), are usually suggested:

1. Boot from created image: by attaching image to Virtual Machine or by restoring backup (extracting image) onto second disk and selecting that as a boot drive. This method is statistical: it’s based on making some selection (say, 100,000 files that needed for system start from 5,000,000  files total), and if files in this selection are consistent (which is confirmed by normal start and functioning of the OS), then estimation (“extrapolation”) that all other files are consistent too can be made. By launching installed software some more files can be checked in a similar manner. But, let’s say, there are several hundreds of files in standard Windows “Documents” directory: corruption of one of these files simply won’t be revealed by this method. The same applies to system files that don’t participate directly in boot and in general accessed by the OS rather infrequently (some *.dll-files, for example)
2. Direct “side-by-side” comparison of drive and its image contents. For example, using software like Beyond Compare, WinDIFF, WinMerge, etc. But such software works on filesystem (files & folders) level, and I think, that’s not the best way: even if offline OS is considered, mounting of a filesystem (in the another OS) is required (because this software works with “something with letter”, like “C:”, “H:”, etc.), so:

   - Backups of partitions like MSR (Microsoft Reserved Partition), at least, can’t be verified & validated using this approach (because they simply don’t contain any mountable filesystem)
   - Windows (and other OS`s too, I think) can perform (and usually performs rather actively) writes to mounted filesystems (Windows, at least, in `System Volume Information` folder, for example), and comparing with dynamically changing object ─ certainly not a good idea
   - Plus, NTFS Permissions can block access to system files during comparison. Not sure here, because I am not very familiar with NTFS permissions system, but checked on recent “Windows To Go” installation and indeed, at least for `R:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6\pq` access was blocked. But this point may be treated as unconfirmed, presumable (and clarification in answers or in comments would be great, of course)
   - And as one more “additional” point: file system mounting can be not good in terms of security. For example, when copying potentially unsafe systems “under” the main system. But so-called “Live OS`s” can be used here. Or VMs (but I haven't tested VMs for this yet)
3. Running “in-house” verification function. It’s very convenient, but this method doesn’t reveal incorrect settings or bugs in backup software itself or in “data providers” (VSS, for example), because of which some data just can be not included in the backup. In other words, this approach checks that **some data was transferred properly**, roughly like this:

   > Block №10 has hash `3500BA09D0538297440CA620C9DD46BF` on disk and hash `3500BA09D0538297440CA620C9DD46BF` in created image => copied correctly;
   > Block №500 has hash `FAE8A9257E154175DA4193DBF6552EF6` on disk and hash `FAE8A9257E154175DA4193DBF6552EF6` in created image => copied correctly;
   > Block №2500 has hash `7F138A09169B250E9DCB378140907378` on disk and hash `7F138A09169B250E9DCB378140907378` in created image => copied correctly;
   > …

   But doesn’t check that **just right data was copied**: that blocks №10, №500 and №2500 – are precisely what we are interested in
4. Combinations of all of the above-stated methods

## Question itself

So, the main idea is to find out (or create) one more and most strength (powerful) checking process (technique), that can replace all listed methods or, of course, can be used in addition to them. It can also be considered as **the method of checking backup software itself**. Speed and ease of such technique may be not that great (they are not in priority). I suppose, such complete checking method should be “Hash-Based”, but it’s just an assumption (that’s why my question is here)

## Additional comment

And here are my ideas of how this can be realized (3 approaches, sorted by convenience of V&V). The text is rather long, but it’s more like an additional comment, something like my own small research, that I included just in case. So, it’s not necessary to read it to understand the main question (because the main question is fully described above). I introduce here two systems, denoted just as System №1 and System №2: System №1 – OS that should be copied, System №2 – OS that performs backup process. So, here is my additional comment

> ### Approach №1
>
> Make Image directly from system №1. Not the best option in terms of verification, because just after image creation files on the source disk will be modified by this system (logs, temp files, etc.). Yes, here it is better to compare not with the files on drive itself, but open (mount) VSS snapshot for comparison. But all of the questions and challenges of such comparison listed in point №2 above also applies here
>
> And here is one more thing. Commonly, Backup Software also copies not the “dynamic” files itself, but the data from VSS snapshots. But here only comparison of data assembled by VSS with the data copied by the Backup Software from VSS into image file is performed. And, I think, some bugs may be present in VSS, because of which not all of the data will be “transferred” to VSS snapshot, and from there to the Backup Software. And this comparison confirms that copy “VSS Snapshot -> Image File” was performed without errors, but it doesn’t confirm that the whole copying process “Real Data on Disk -> VSS Snapshot -> Image File” was done properly. So, yes, the main idea of point №3 above, but described in more detail
>
> ### Approach №2
>
> Power-off system №1, boot system №2 and create image (of system №1, that is now offline) from it. Offline system can be viewed as just a bunch of “static” files and folders ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394424/do-multiple-operating-systems-affect-the-performance-of-a-computer/1394426#1394426)), thus rather complex Online-OS backup process reduces to just properly copying all of these “offline”-files, which is a much simpler task. Data for copying (to the image) now based directly on the $MFT file (and other NTFS metafiles), I suppose. Much better than VSS copy, because one layer (which adds complexity and, presumably, bugs) is now removed, but still some errors are possible (due to NTFS metafiles corruption, for example; discussed, for instance, [here](https://backupchain.com/i/backup-verification-validation) in the section “What About Verifying a Disk Image or Disk Clone?”). After that open original disk and its image and compare. For example, how stated above in point №2. Or with additional methods:
>
> - By computing (and comparing) hashes (say, SHA256) “from” corresponding directories (for example, “Windows” directory) on disk and on image (for example, using 7-Zip). But, as stated above: permissions can potentially block access. Plus, symbolic links (for example, “Documents and Settings”, that persists in the root of system drive and points to  `C:\Users`; presumably, for backward-compatibility) add complexity to hashing. Plus, metadata somehow should also be included in generated hashes
> - By comparing sizes of corresponding folders and the number of files and subfolders in them. Not very reliable comparison method
> - By just “visually” comparing the contents of disk and image (with file managers, for example). Also not very reliable. And this is semi-manual and not very effective method
>   But it’s not the best approach too, as also stated above in point №2. And in general: comparing contents on files & folders level looks not very convenient and efficient
>
> ### Approach №3
>
> Power-off system №1, boot system №2 and create an image (of offline system №1) from it. But after that compute hashes not for individual files and folders, but for the entire disk (disk’s content) and its image (image’s content). Disk hashing can be done (for example, in HxD) without file system mounting. And hashes match will give 100%-guarantees (hash collisions can be just ignored, especially in case of SHA256, SHA512 or similar algorithm with extremely low probability of collisions; moreover, even less “strong” hashes like MD5 can be used as we are expecting contents to be identical and, at least, not modified by purpose) that contents stored on original (physical) disk and in image are exactly the same. But it seems that some writes can be done even to not mounted volumes ([reference №1](https://www.klennet.com/imager/hash-stability.aspx), [reference №2](https://web.archive.org/web/20190829145255/http:/www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Forensic_Live_CD_issues), [reference №3](https://superuser.com/questions/1565508/are-forensic-usb-write-blockers-ok-to-use-during-data-backup-on-windows-10#comment2384496_1565508)), so here a so-called “Write Blocker” should be attached to fully prevent disk writes. But OK, let’s allow some writes, because they should be rather small (seems like only “service” operations are performed, i. e. not Gigabytes of data are written). But in that case hashing entire disk at once is not the best strategy: because hash functions are extremely nonlinear “by design”[^1]. This (not wanted in our case) property of hashes can be reduced (or even fully eliminated) by splitting data into “chunks” or “blocks” (thereby reducing strength, but, again, it’s not a true cryptographic case), say, 1GiB or 10 000 blocks each. This approach realized (implemented), for example, in [Atola hardware-software complexes](https://atola.com/products/insight/), and they call it [“Segmented Hashing”](https://atola.com/products/insight/segmented-hashing.html). So, something like this will be obtained as a result of applying “Segmented Hashing”:
>
> `Blocks 0-10 000, SHA256: 249CB3CB46FD875196E7ED4A8736271A64FF2D8132357222A283BE53E7232ED3`
> `Blocks 10 001-20 000, SHA256: 92F24FED2BA2927173AAD58981F6E0643C6B89815B117E8A7C4A0988AC918170`
> `…`
>
> Both for initial drive and its image. If mismatches will appear, they will be “localized” “to” some range (say, blocks 210 001 – 220 000). After that “hash range” can be reduced (to 100 blocks, for example), and areas of differences can be detected more precisely. And then direct analysis can be performed to find out whether this difference occurred due to error in imaging process or due to just a small “service” writes to the volume. But here direct (“Bit-By-Bit”) comparison may be more optimal (discussed, for example, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/comparison-of-raw-block-devices))
>
> Also, backup software often creates not a RAW disk image (that consists of **all** data on accessible disk space, including, for example, unallocated, or marked as free, space), but copies only allocated space (i. e. occupied by the filesystem) to reduce image size. And that’s very convenient. But that can be a source of false hashes mismatching, because:
>
> 1. In case of storage devices without TRIM (typically conventional CMR Hard Drives) data in unallocated space on source disk (in such “linear” hashing) will “contribute” to Hash, when in corresponding blocks in the image will be just zeros, I suppose
> 2. In case of storage devices with TRIM (typically SSDs and SMR Hard Drives) things (presumably) become easier, because in that case unallocated (at least due to deletion) space will be filled with zeros both on original disk and on its image. But, I think, here also may be some particularities (for example, with overwritten files, etc.) that can generate non-matching hashes
>
> Of course, this peculiarity can be eliminated by making RAW images with, for example, “dd”. But “dd” is not as convenient as backup software (for example, doesn’t offer incremental or differential images)
>
> And looks like verification by hashing can produce a lot of mismatches, and each such case should be thoroughly reviewed to find out the source of such mismatch:
>
> - Whether it’s a real error in data copy
>   -Whether it’s just “technical writes” (low-level OS and FS things) that make only insignificant changes and don’t affect the “main” data
> - Whether it’s optimizations in images (that done by backup software) and corresponding difference in disk and image structures due to these optimizations
>
> That’s why further development (of this approach) is needed here

## Conclusion

Well, yes, that’s my question, my thoughts and ideas. Thank you for your attention. Looking forward to hear opinions and answers, of course

---

<sub>[^1]: Hash “reflects” only presence of difference in data, and says nothing about why, where and in which amount this modification took place. So, the hash can be altered completely and by modification of just 1 bit, and by modification of 5GiB of data, and by modification of the entire data on disk</sub>